# Swagger - Extending SwaggerSpecFilter

Tags: java, spring, swagger

I'm trying to write my own Swagger API Filter to hide certain things from appearing in the API.  I think I have a pretty good idea of what I *should* be doing but I must be missing something in the details.

I'm using Swagger Core 1.3.10 and Spring 3.1.  Here's some of what I have now:

**SwaggerApiAuthorizationFilter**

```
public class SwaggerApiAuthorizationFilter implements SwaggerSpecFilter {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SwaggerApiAuthorizationFilter.class);

    @Override
    public boolean isOperationAllowed(Operation operation, ApiDescription api, Map<String, List<String>> params, 
            Map<String, String> cookies, Map<String, List<String>> headers) {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isParamAllowed(Parameter parameter, Operation operation, ApiDescription api, Map<String, List<String>> params, 
            Map<String, String> cookies, Map<String, List<String>> headers) {

        // do not allow the documentation to be generated on parameters that have their access set to "internal"
        if (parameter.paramAccess().isDefined() && parameter.paramAccess().get().equalsIgnoreCase("internal")) {

            logger.debug("The following parameter has been hidden from the Swagger API documentation: " + parameter.name());

            return false;

        } else {

            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

**SwaggerServlet**

```
public class SwaggerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SwaggerServlet.class);

    BeanConfig beanConfig;
    SwaggerApiAuthorizationFilter swaggerApiAuthorizationFilter;

    public void setBeanConfig(BeanConfig beanConfig) {
        this.beanConfig = beanConfig;
    }

    public void setSwaggerApiAuthorizationFilter(SwaggerApiAuthorizationFilter swaggerApiAuthorizationFilter) {
        this.swaggerApiAuthorizationFilter = swaggerApiAuthorizationFilter;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {
        try {

            super.init(servletConfig);

            beanConfig.setBasePath("/mbl/services");
            beanConfig.setVersion("1.0");
            beanConfig.setResourcePackage("com.whatever.resources");
            beanConfig.setScan(true);

            FilterFactory.setFilter(swaggerApiAuthorizationFilter);

            logger.debug("The Swagger servlet has been initialized");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**spring config file**

```
<!-- Swagger Configuration and Providers -->
<bean id="beanConfig" class="com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig">
    <property name="title" value="Java API"/>
    <property name="version" value="1.0" />
    <property name="basePath" value="/mbl/services"/>
    <property name="resourcePackage" value="com.whatever.resources"/>
    <property name="scan" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="swaggerApiAuthorizationFilter" class="com.whatever.util.SwaggerApiAuthorizationFilter" />
```

**web.xml**

```
<!-- Enabling Swagger servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Swagger Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.whatever.web.SwaggerServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>swagger.filter</param-name>
            <param-value>com.whatever.util.SwaggerApiAuthorizationFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>-1</load-on-startup> 
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Swagger Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api-docs</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Resource class**

```
    public Response getUserInfo( 
    @Context HttpHeaders headers, 
    @ApiParam(name="brand", access="internal") @CookieParam(value = "brand") String brand) {
```

It appears that my SwaggerApiAuthorizationFilter isn't even being called.  My guess is that something is wrong in my configuration either in the web.xml or the SwaggerServlet.  Does anyone see anything above that looks incorrect or does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've just used the filter successfully. I had problems to make filter function properly. The problem was that there was a problem to find my filter's implemention class. When I changed the package to a place where swagger's class could access, everything funtioned correctly. Next, I just had to implement my logic on my filter class. My filter class implemented the interface SwaggerSpecFilter too. Best regards.

I'm using DefaultJaxrsConfig:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Jersey2Config</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>io.swagger.jaxrs.config.DefaultJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>api.version</param-name>
        <param-value>1.0.0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
        <param-value>/my-service/service/</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>swagger.filter</param-name>
        <param-value>mypackage.SwaggerFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing but I think you need to implement Filter as well as the SwaggerSpecFilter interface instead of extending HttpServlet (looking at the source it does not appear SwaggerSpecFilter extends Filter as one would expect), then configure it as a filter in your web.xml instead of a servlet. It would be something like this:

`<filter>
    <filter-name>Swagger Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.whatever.util.SwaggerApiAuthorizationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Swagger Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/api-docs</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>`

Again, not sure if this will work but just a guess off the top of my head.